# Problems with CSS Box-Shadow:Inset on image

Tags: css

I'm trying to replicate the CSS 'Vignette' effect, [detailed on Trent Walton's site](http://trentwalton.com/2010/11/22/css-box-shadowinset/).

```
.vignette1 {
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 85px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 85px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 85px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  float: left;
}

.vignette1 img {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;

  width: 320px;
  height: 247px;
}
```

It works well in isolation, but has problems on my production site, where the background settings for a parent div override the z-index on the image - live jsFiddle [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/7xqPC/).

The second approach - mentioned in the original article's comments and included in the demo - works well, but my image has to be wrapped in the  tag - it can't be below it.

Comment: It's best to describe the actual problem here. Blogs change or get taken down over time. If that happens the question becomes useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end I found the' Overlay & Inset Method', the second of [Jordon Dobsons's techniques](http://jordandobson.com/_expirements/css/vignette/) to be the most effective and least reliant on negative z-indexes:

```
/* Border & Vignette Setup */

    figure{
      position:               relative;
      display:                block;
      line-height:            0;
      width:                  500px;
      height:                 333px;
      margin-bottom:          2em;
      border:                 1em solid #fff;
      -webkit-box-shadow:     0 .1em .3em rgba(0,0,0,.25);
      -moz-box-shadow:        0 .1em .3em rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    }

    figure::before{
      content:                "";
      position:               absolute;
      top:                    -1em;
      bottom:                 -1em;
      left:                   -1em;
      right:                  -1em;

    }

    figure::before,
    figure img{
      outline:                1px solid #ccc;    
    }

    figure.vignette img{
      z-index:                1;
      position:               relative;
      display:                block;
      width:                  100%;
      height:                 100%;

    }

/* Overlay & Inset Method */

    figure.overlay.inset::after{

    /* Mozilla Settings */
      -moz-box-shadow:        inset 0 0 150px rgba(0,0,0,.75);    

    /* Webkit Setting */
      -webkit-box-shadow:     inset 0 0 150px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    }
```

([jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kDJUa/) using original layout)

Answer (score 8):

page has a solid white background, you're giving the image a z-index of -1, so it's going underneath that div. There are several workarounds, depending on how your final design is going to look, but if you just make #page transparent it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/tA8EA/

Or you can also set page to position realtive and give it a lower z-index than the image:
http://jsfiddle.net/PEgBv/

Comment: It has to have the white background in the parent div... setting it transparent isn't an option.

Comment: Then you must set a lower z-index for #page. Solution updated with the alternative.

Comment: Great stuff, thanks Duopixel - I'd tried setting the z-index lower on #page, but forgot to set position:relative.

Comment: .... problem is, setting the z-index negative, drops any links or elements within that div out of focus meaning they can't be clicked on or used - see my updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PEgBv/1/

Answer (score 0):

I've post an answer with dynamic image list loading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10371341/1363973). Instead of under-z-indexed image there's just DIVs with background-image and image dimensions set.