# I am trying to give "box-shadow" to my image but i doesn't works

Tags: html, image, css, shadow

Can u tell me what is wrong with my code?Why there is no shadow on image?
Here is my code:
**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/aVt9qPi.png"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.wrapper img{
-moz-box-shadow:inset 1px 2px 18px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 1px 2px 18px #000000;
box-shadow:inset 1px 2px 18px #000000;
}
```

U can find working demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Aq2jR/1/)**

Comment: Try and place 'inset' at the end

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076045/rendering-css3-inset-shadow-with-an-image

your answer is here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cannot apply shadow `inset` effect directly on image. Better apply it on the div.

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pukupaqo/3/edit)**.

```
div.wrapper{
-moz-box-shadow:inset 1px 2px 18px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 1px 2px 18px #000000;
box-shadow:inset 1px 2px 18px #000000;
}

div.wrapper img{
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: @web-tiki now it will work? no other reason to give down-voting

Comment: Thanks, i used that :D

Answer (score 2):

Inset shadows do not work on image tags, but you can wrap your img in a parent element to achieve the same effect.

[See this solution for an example.](http://bavotasan.com/2011/adding-inset-shadow-to-image-css3/)